# SELECT query slowing down the wal replay in replication server

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

While running a `SELECT` query (bit large query ~1GB of data output which took ~15minutes to execute) in hot standby replication host, its halts the wal archiving process. Once the Query done with the execution, the replication takes place and started replicating. Is that normal behaviour of postgres or need to tune system runtime configuration?

I have tried to change `work_mem=64MB` to `work_mem=96MB`, but still I couldn't solve the delay.

(using PG 9.5)

Comment: Are you running the query on Master or slave? If its a slave, i think the replication stops because incoming committed data is in the same table from where data is being fetched by the query. Try running in master and see if there is any difference.

Comment: Does the `SELECT` do any writes via some functions etc? If so, yes, that's expected if `hot_standby_feedback` is enabled on the replica.

Comment: @Lohit, Its running on slave. And I can't execute the query in master since its having frequent updates / inserts.

Comment: @Craig, No. Its running as direct query (directly via psql and output written to a file). And yes, the parameter is on. **pass upstream** make any difference if I disable it?

Comment: @Spike if that is the case, then it is expected behavior, as the frequent updates/inserts cannot be written to slave table when it is locked by the select query/vice versa. I would suggest you look at the patterns when inserts/updates are coming in master, and schedule the select query in slave when the dmls are not coming in master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication can be delayed if a query on the standby needs data the master has removed. The WAL from the master with the resource removal cannot be replayed until the standby query finishes, or the standby query must be cancelled.

You can:

- Let the standby cancel the query after a time limit - see the `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_stremaing_delay` parameters; or
- Enable `hot_standby_feedback` on the standby so the master won't remove resources the standby needs while its queries are running. This isn't perfect, conflicts that delay replication or cause query cancels can still happen when the standby just recently started up. But it helps.